# Digits counter in c++

Tags: c++

As the title says, I have to find out the number of digits in a given number. Here's my code which gives me a result of 0 when the number goes above 10
Programming in Visual Studio Pro 2012

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int g, count=0;

    cout << "Enter the number" << endl;
    cin >> g;

    while (g > 0)
    {
        count = count +1;
        g = g/10;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks chris but I just started learning C++. Can you please explain how that is done ?

Comment: What makes you believe the looping condition should be `(g > 0 && g <= 10)` ? It should be simpler!

Comment: Why not take it as a string and get the size?

Comment: @BobbyDigital Leading zeros?

Comment: Ohh sorry sorry I used that to try an if statement it shouldn't be there

Comment: With that `while` condition, do you expect anything *besides* 0 or 1 to be returned? Why not simply `while (g > 0)`, or even `while (g)` and I assume you intentionally discounted the user entering `0`, which will automatically return 0-digits.

Comment: Yeah guys I tried it with g > 10 and it returned 0 whenever a number bigger than 10 is entered

Comment: @user2834298, Pick some numbers, n, and compute log10(n). You should notice a pattern with respect to the number of digits n has.

Comment: Solution using `std::log10` : http://ideone.com/MSyrG8

Comment: How can I use this logarithm base 10 thingy ?

Comment: And how does it mathematically work to give me the number of digits ?

Comment: See Nawaz' link above.

Comment: @user2834298: You use it as : `int count =  std::floor(std::log10(input)+1);` and you're done. **No Raw Loop!** [Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/MSyrG8).

Comment: But you may get a low grade if using `std::log10`. The exercise is probably to make you understand simple loops and assignments...

Comment: @Nawaz: until somebody enters -1, that is.

Comment: @SigTerm: Is that not detectable?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's the point. because we still did not take the cmath library or the logarithms

Comment: Please take some minutes to **think** about all the help given in answers and comments (or else give up the goal of learning programming). Don't expect us to do your (simple) homework - and if we did that won't help you to *understand* and **learn** things.

Comment: @john: Perhaps then the question should be "...significant digits..."?

Answer (score 3):

Did you do any debugging?

What value of g do you think will make this condition true ?

```
(g > 0 && g <= 10)
```

This should be enough for you to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if g is > 10, then

`(g > 0 && g<=10)` is false.

Answer (score 0):

This code will reproduce the number of digits.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int g, count=0;
    cout << "Enter the number" << endl;
    cin >> g;
    while (g > 0)
    {
        count = count +1;
        g /= 10;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Beside this, there's another way to solve this problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int g, count=0;
    cout << "Enter the number" << endl;
    cin >> g;
    count = (int)(log10((double)g));
    if (g == 0)
        count = 0;
    cout << count + 1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem #1: user enters -100. Problem #2: user enters 2150000000.

Comment: Second solution: returns invalid result on negative numbers, and returns invalid result on positive numbers. Enter "9", see what happens.

Comment: `(int)(log10((double)g));` is wrong. Try for `g=999`.

Comment: In case of problem 2, use variable long

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a loop for this (a log10-call can do the job), use something like this (not tested):

```
for (count=0;g>0;g/=10,count++) {}
```

Which is almost the same you wrote, but without the `g<10`-condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit cumbersome to first convert a string to an int and then try to find its length. Why don't you just look at the string?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Enter the number" << std::endl;

  std::string g;
  std::cin >> g;

  std::cout << g.size() << "\n";
}
```

Note: This will not trim leading zeroes; I leave this to you.